# Do knockouts earn more points in ranked mode?

Tags: splatoon-3

If my team wins a ranked Anarchy Battle as a knockout (ie: a victory before the match timer runs out), does that earn more points for my skill rank than a game where the team scores were closer?

[image: a knockout game]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In anarchy battles, you will always get 8 points on your rank for a win. Any way the win came.

What changes is the points lost on a loss. -1 on C, -2 on B, -3 on A, -4 on S and -5 on S+. It is also unbothered by how you lost, just that you lost.

https://splatoonwiki.org/wiki/Rank

It is currently unknown for series battles, but I would guess it doesnt change anything either. The research is still going on but as far as we know, the points got at the end of the series is a number for each win, plus 1p per silver medal and 5p per gold.

https://splatoonwiki.org/wiki/Anarchy_Battle